# Check two consecutive values in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional php array like this

```
$array[0]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 10);
$array[1]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 20);
$array[2]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 30);
$array[3]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 40);
$array[4]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 50);
$array[5]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 60);
$array[6]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 70);
```

I want to get `numbers` of `$array[4]` and `$array[5]` because There is no `Missed` between them. How can i do this with php. What is the simplist way?

OUTPUT

```
50 and 60
```

Comment: There is also no `Missed` between 5 and 6. How do you want to handle that? Do you only want the first results?

Comment: i only want first two matching result and avoid all others

Comment: What about $array[5] and $array[6]?  They don't have a 'Missed' between them, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$array[0]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 10);
$array[1]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 20);
$array[2]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 30);
$array[3]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 40);
$array[4]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 50);
$array[5]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 60);
$array[6]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 70);
$last_status = '';
$last_number = '';
foreach($array as $foo){
    if($foo['status'] == $last_status && $last_status == 'Waiting'){
        echo "$last_number and $foo[number]";
        break;
    }
    $last_status = $foo['status'];
    $last_number = $foo['number'];
}
?>
```

**[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/XiAUg0hB)**

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($array[$i - 1]['status'] == 'Waiting' && $array[$i]['status'] == 'Waiting') {
        echo $array[$i - 1]['number'] . ' AND ' . $array[$i]['number'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
$array[0]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 10);
$array[1]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 20);
$array[2]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 30);
$array[3]   =   array('status' => 'Missed' , 'number' => 40);
$array[4]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 50);
$array[5]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 60);
$array[6]   =   array('status' => 'Waiting' , 'number' => 70);

array_walk(
      $array
    , function ($value, $index, &$prev) {
        if ($value['status'] == $prev['status'] && $prev['status'] == 'Waiting') {
            echo $prev['number'] . ' AND ' . $value['number'] . PHP_EOL;
        }       

        $prev = $value; 

    }, array(
          'status' => ''
        , 'number' => 0
    )
);
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3kWbsd)